# Is Remote Display API deprecated? Is it possible to draw directly on a Chromecast display from an Android app?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I would like to render a custom View onto a TV/Cast-enabled device.

Is this currently possible? It seems like it was at some point but all documentation and references about it seem to be rather old and obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote display API is not supported anymore and we do not have an alternative as of now.